Understanding Generalized Stokes Theorem in Classical Vector Calculus
Following this question, I'm trying to understand the Generalized Stokes Theorem and its specific cases without resorting to the notation of differential forms, which I find unintuitive. Specifically, I'm interested in expressing the theorem in the language of classical vector calculus for an m-dimensional manifold M in an n-dimensional space, where m is smaller or equal to n.
The theorem is commonly written in differential forms as:
$$
\oint_{\partial M} \omega = \int_{M} d\omega
$$
However, I'm looking for a way to express this using classical vector calculus notations, such as:
$$
\oint_{\partial M} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_{M} (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec{A}
$$
Here, I'm struggling with the meanings of $d\vec{r}$, $d\vec{A}$, and the curl operator $\nabla \times$ in higher dimensions.
To give context, I'm familiar with:

Green's Theorem for a 1D curve surrounding a 2D area in 2D space.
The specific case of Stokes' Theorem, which extends Green's theorem to a 2D membrane in 3D space with a 3D curve boundary.
The Gauss Divergence Theorem where a 2D membrane encompasses a 3D control volume.

Can anyone provide insights or resources on how to translate the Generalized Stokes Theorem into the framework of classical vector calculus for higher dimensions?

When $M$ is a four-dimensional solid then $\partial M$ is a three-dimensional object and $\int_{\partial M} \omega$ is a volume integral having an orientation (ie. the order of $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ matters). The RHS $\int_M,d\omega$ is a four dimensional hypervolume integral with orientation. The phenomenal strength of differential forms is that they translate themselves into the framework of classical vector calculus in higher dimensions thereby leaving behind what does not exist there:    curl for example.

The classical vector calculus is called classical for a reason! It is highly restrictive and works only in 3 dimensions (and exploits lots of special and honestly very adhoc features of $\Bbb{R}^3$). You only find it intuitive because that’s what you’ve been told is intuitive (even the entire notation is a hack and a scam… $\nabla\times$ is not even a literal cross product). Differential forms are the much more natural way of describing things, and they work in all dimensions (since we’re using the right tools for the job). So the answer is you can’t, without doing some super adhoc stuff.

People have long been after the question of how best to generalize the theorems of Gauss-Ostrogradsky (divergence theorem), Green, Kelvin-Stokes, etc because they noticed so many similarities in their contents. The solution to this problem is via differential forms; they provide a systematic, and honestly much easier language to work with (you only need to know two or three properties of $d$ and you know it all), giving you the fully general theorem in one go. But now you’re asking to translate all this back to vector calculus type language, so you’re literally taking a step back.

It's a good question. Even with Stokes theorem, it is non-trivial to obtain the vector calculus identities. The are derived in this section 4.4 of this book https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

@Kakashi, thanks a lot. Do you mind if I review the book and ask questions in this comment section?

@Foad Ask questions on stackexchange, not in the comments section.
